# Pandas dataframe calculation based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, function, calculation

I have two dataframe and i need to use 1 as a reference to calculate the other values.

For example, I have `df` like this:

```
Brand    LB_ID       Score
BMW      Class       98
BMW      Cost        99
VW       Class       85
VW       Cost        70
```

And the other `df_lb` like this

```
Brand     Total
BMW       56
VW        180
```

I need to use this formula to calculate another column:  `(Score(df) / Total(df_lb)) * 100`

Normally I can use if-else conditions for such data but I have big data and it will take a lot time to write hundreds of if_else lines...  I need an efficient way? Is there any?

Comment: Is possible if no match? Then whats happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for new `Series` by `Brand` in second DataFrame used for divide by `Score` column and multiple by `100` for new column:

```
df['new'] = df['Score'].div(df['Brand'].map(df_lb.set_index('Brand')['Total'])).mul(100)
print (df)
  Brand  LB_ID  Score         new
0   BMW  Class     98  175.000000
1   BMW   Cost     99  176.785714
2    VW  Class     85   47.222222
3    VW   Cost     70   38.888889
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `Brand` as the index for both dataframes and divide :

```
df["new"] = (df.set_index("Brand")
               .Score
               .div(df_lb.set_index("Brand").Total)
              .mul(100)
              .array)

df


   Brand    LB_ID   Score   new
0   BMW     Class   98  175.000000
1   BMW     Cost    99  176.785714
2   VW      Class   85  47.222222
3   VW      Cost    70  38.888889
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge first

```
m = df.merge(df_lb)
```

and then compute your new column

```
m['new'] = 100 * m['Score'] / m['Total']
```